# How to synthesize alloys or new materials on a small scale?

Tags: materials, metallurgy, material-science

At the lab scale, alloys or intermetallic compounds are synthesized in an arc melting furnace or by induction melting. The quantity produced is about 5 to 10 grams at minimum. **My question is, what if I want to synthesize less than 2 grams, what should be the synthesis route?**

Comment: Anything that can reach the temperatures, pressures, and any other conditions you require. Laser, arc, induction are all just ways to heat, and a furnace is a container for that.